# Ubuntu 14.04 login loop after changing username

Tags: 14.04, login

I see that this problem has happened many times, and I've tried the suggestions but have not been able to solve the issue.

Following instructions I found to change the username, I entered recovery mode and entered

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

and then changed the username from 'djvanel' to:

```
usermod student
```

I also changed the password. Then when I try to log in with the GUI, it accepts my password, the screen turns black for about a second, then it comes back to the login screen. I can still log into a shell. I have tried:

```
chown student:student ~/.Xauthority
```

then it gives back 'no such file or directory'. I also tried installing gmd and that also didn't work. I also reinstalled ubuntu-desktop. Now when I go back to recovery mode and change back my username and password, I still get the login loop.

Comment: What `usermod` command(s) did you execute, exactly? what did you do with the user's home directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Do the following in grub recovery root:

```
mv -v /home/your-old-username /home/your-new-username
chown -Rv username:groupname /home/your-new-username
```

Replace respective the porper foldernames and usernames groupnames to fit your situation.

Comment: I have done this. My username:groupname is now student:student, the directory is /home/student, and I used chown in the way you described. The login still loops

Comment: You might as well remove the following file `rm ~/.Xauthority`